# URI в proxy_pass создает ошибку (запрещает использовать URI)

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, proxypass

Есть nginx-конфиг:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name test.en.sitename1.ru;

  root /srv/docroot/;

  ssl_certificate         SSL_CERT;
  ssl_certificate_key     SSL_KEY;
  ssl_trusted_certificate SSL_CHAIN_CERT;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

  limit_conn perip 10;

  access_log off;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @node;
  }

  location @node {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With";

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age'        86400;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
      return 204;
    }

    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://node:3012;
  }
}
```

Запускается через Docker, `node` (`proxy_pass http://node:3012;`) — имя контейнера.

На стороне ноды проект роутится по принципу `/:project/:lang/<site>`. Нужно настроить `proxy_pass` таким образом, чтобы определённый `:project` и `:lang` вели на конкретный `server_name`.

---

UPD

Завели.

Сейчас конфиг такой:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name test.lang.example.com;

  root /srv/docroot/;

  ssl_certificate         SSL_CERT;
  ssl_certificate_key     SSL_KEY;
  ssl_trusted_certificate SSL_CHAIN_CERT;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

  limit_conn perip 10;

  access_log off;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @node;
  }

  location @node {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With";

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age'        86400;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
      return 204;
    }

    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://node:3012;
  }
}

Должно быть так:

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name test.lang.example.com;

  root /srv/docroot/;

  ssl_certificate         SSL_CERT;
  ssl_certificate_key     SSL_KEY;
  ssl_trusted_certificate SSL_CHAIN_CERT;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

  limit_conn perip 10;

  access_log off;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @node;
  }

  location @node {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With";

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age'        86400;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
      return 204;
    }

    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://node:3012/example/lang;
  }
}
```

Т. е. обращение в браузере к  test.lang.example.com должно относительно проксироваться на http://node:3012/example/lang в докере.

Comment: Так и не понял как связаны вопрос в заголовке и текст. Что значит «вели на конкретный server_name”?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Нужно написать

`server_name  test.en.sitename1.ru;
proxy_pass  http://node:3012/sitename1/en`

и

`server_name  test.en.sitename2.ru;
proxy_pass  http://node:3012/sitename2/en`

Но в этом случае `nginx` ругается, что в `proxy_pass` нельзя писать if-условий (или как-то так) и что нужно использовать только хост и порт в `proxy_pass`

Comment: Зачем вам тут server_name? Кажется вы не очень понимаете что эта директива делает и на самом деле вам нужен `proxy_set_header Host ...`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Так и proxy_set_header Host тоже есть. А proxy_pass должен быть на уровне location, server_name на уровне сервера.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Не совсем понятно, что именно нужно сделать для того чтобы их разделить и при этом не показывать в окончательном урле /:project/:lang/

Comment: Ну так заведите два серверных блока. Я всё ещё не понимаю что куда должно проксироваться. Покажите примеры адресов и куда они должны вести (полные адреса).

Comment: @AlexeyTen завели, добавила обновление в вопрос. «Относительно» — т. е. url http://test.lang.example.com/hello должно проксироваться в http://node:3012/example/lang/hello

Comment: @AlexeyTen т.е. 2 серверных блока не удается настроить таким образом